# Can't use ternary for return null

Tags: c#

I want replicate this condition:

```
string responseText = getData();     
if(responseText == null){ return; }
```

with the ternary operator, what I tried is:

```
 responseText == null ? return : null;
```

but  I get `return` underlined in red with:

> return is not a valid term for the expression.

Essentially I want stop the code of this function with a return if `responseText` is null, instead if is different against `null` I need to continue my code. What I did wrong?

Comment: `if(responseText == null) return` is your best bet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ternary operator is used for assignment:

```
string a = isEmpty ? item : null; //this is OK
```

If you assign nothing, you cannot use the ternary operation.

```
response == null ? return : null; //what is this??
```

What you have done, is likely already correct:

```
if (responseText == null)
    return;
//do something else when text is not null
```

Comment: I wonder why there is a downvote here while I explain that OP practice to return early is already correct

Comment: I downvoted it, because the answer says that you can only use the ternary operator for assignment, and that is incorrect.  You can use it for any expression, even if you don't assign the result to anything

Comment: @SamIam we cannot use ternary operation to control the flow of the program alone without assignment (or rather, I should say, when you `return` you still have to assign something to be returned). I.e. there isn't such thing like `a ? f() : b();` - just methods

Comment: @Ian I upvote also, thanks for this explaination, I don't working on c# on a long time. I'm afraid that I got some downvote.

Comment: @SamIam I disagree. Because your expression will be returning something to evaluated. You cannot have it independently

Comment: @Ian that is also incorrect.  code like `ShowMessage( iSuccess ? GetSuccessMessage() : GetFailureMessage());` will compile and run.  It also doesn't do assignment

Comment: @SamIam yes, but the result is captured in the show message argument - it is an assignment to the `ShowMessage` argument. so, it *is* an assignment. You cannot have an independent line with `isSuccess ? GetSuccessMessage() : GetFailureMessage()` alone as if you choose between two statements for a code line by ternary operation

Comment: @Ian `if(x == (c ? a : b)){do stuff}` is also valid, and also does not do assignment

Comment: @SamIam again, the result is captured to the `if` statement. Basically, you got to capture the result.

Comment: @Ian I'm sure it gets stored to memory somewhere, but that's not really assignment

Comment: @SamIam the point here is you cannot use ternary operation without capturing the result somewhere... not sure what you mean by not an assignment when you clearly have to capture the result. If what you mean is that it must have a variable - then I also disagree that it must have a variable. What I agree on is that it cannot be used without capturing the value (assigning the value to the if conditional statement in this case).

Comment: @Ian `In computer programming, an assignment statement sets and/or re-sets the value stored in the storage location(s) denoted by a variable name; in other words, it copies a value into the variable. In most imperative programming languages, the assignment statement (or expression) is a fundamental construct.` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_science%29

Comment: @SamIam please note the last phrase: `the assignment statement (or expression)` And expression is fundamentally an assignment statement to anonymous variable (so to speak) - returning true or false.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of a ternary operator is to be able to create an expression that uses conditions.

It's not intended for controlling the flow of your program, and you shouldn't attempt to use it that way.

Stick with your `if` statement.

Comment: Yes. Also using the ternary operator in this case would decrease the readability of the code imho.

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator is an *expression* - it returns one value or the other based on the condition.  You are trying to use it for *program flow* which is not possible.

I see nothing wrong with your `if` statement - is it clear, concise, and most importantly, *it works*.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return `return`. The returned value must be a variable of the same type as the one receiving the ternary expression's result.

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator evaluates an expression. It cannot control the flow of your program. Your best bet is to use an old fashioned `if` statement, such as the one you provided in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The operand of a ternary operator should be a expression yielding a value. But in this case return doesn't yields any value.